# Install bleachbit on Centos 8

Tags: centos, software-installation

Could anyone successfully installed `bleachbit` in `CentOS 8`? If yes, please share the way. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation available at https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/install-on-linux.html

Comment: Yes. The `python2-gobject` is actually the `python-gobject`. But this package `python2-scandir` is not available in [centos.pkgs.org](https://centos.pkgs.org/) and I guess I couln'd install? Ok I'll try it with only this package.

Comment: For `python2-scandir` you might need to enable the EPEL repository. Do you need any help in enabling that?

It should only take a
`sudo yum install epel-release && sudo yum check-update`

Comment: I have already enabled it and yum doesn't find it.. Am I doing something wrong? 

Comment: Can you please verify, that EPEL is enabled and that you actually ran `sudo yum check-update`?

Comment: I will verify it and I will update as soon as I go home because I am at work now. (in 6 hours from now) Thanks a lot for your quick responses mate !

Comment: Can you share with us the procedures you have already tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have already enable the EPEL repository. I then did:

```
su
yum update
yum install bleachbit
```

I searched, and found [centos-packages](https://pkgs.org/) and [bleachbit-official](https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/install-on-linux.html)

`python2-gobject` found on packages, but `python2-scandir` not found on packages.

So my conclusion was that I was unable to install it. I will try these at my home very soon.

Comment: Guys you are awesome! I had to install also `dnf install gobject-introspection-devel` and I had to run as root (unfortunately) `pip2 install scandir pygobject vext vext.gi` (because I had an error `running install_lib
    creating /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pygtkcompat
    error: could not create '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pygtkcompat': Permission denied`)
Then running just `python2 bleachbit.py` was ok. Thanks a lot !!!!!

Comment: If one of the answers worked, then you can accept it.

Comment: Sorry for my noob question, but I can not see how I can accept it. I tried to give "this answer is useful" but my reputation is not good for that.

Comment: To the left of the answer, there is an up or down arrow to up and downvote it and a checkmark to accept it.

Comment: I probably don't have it, because I post it as a quest and when I created an account, I am somehow different user, so I suppose that I am not the owner of the post (theoretically)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.bleachbit.org/doc/install-on-linux.html

Rather than just providing the link in the other answer, I'll expand on it:

For CentOS 8, there is a `python3-gobject` but there is no `python-scandir`. As you can see at https://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=25119, the latest version of the latter was released on February 18, 2019 which was before CentOS 8 was released. That's why it's not available in the repos. While there is an `rpm` for `bleachbit` for CentOS 6 and 7 at the first site, there isn't one for CentOS 8.

What I was able to do was to install/run it from source. I couldn't get it to work with Python 3 so I use Python 2 which will still receive security updates throughout the life of CentOS 8.

First, install the following packages with `yum` or `dnf` (enable the PowerTools and Epel repo first):

```
yum install dnf-utils
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
yum-config-manager --enable PowerTools

yum install python2 python2-pip python2-devel python2-setuptools python2-libs pygobject2 cairo-devel gobject-introspection pygobject2-devel cairo-gobject-devel gobject-introspection-devel
```

Then, install the following Python modules with `pip2` (as root):

```
scandir pygobject vext vext.gi
```

Get the source code from here: https://github.com/bleachbit/bleachbit/archive/v3.1.0.tar.gz and decompress it with `tar xvfz v3.1.0.tar.gz` and cd into the `bleachbit-3.1.0` directory. Run the command `python2 bleachbit.py` to open it.

You can set an alias for it in your `.bashrc` or elsewhere along the lines of

```
alias bleachbit="python2 /path/to/bleachbit.py"
```

That way, you can open it from the terminal using your alias `bleachbit`.

Answer (score 0):

Or

wget https://www.bleachbit.org/download/file/t?file=bleachbit-4.0.0-1.1.centos8.noarch.rpm && sudo yum localinstall Downloads/bleachbit-4.0.0-1.1.centos8.noarch.rpm

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. If you say "Or, ..." you will need to reference what the "Either" part was, as the display order of posts depends on post activity and user settings. Also, please use code formatting for verbatim command examples, and add some explanation on why this command will solve the OPs problem (since we try to keep the answers helpful to as wide an audience as possible).